# How to download the latest artifact from Artifactory repository?

Tags: shell, artifactory, continuous-deployment

I need the latest artifact (for example, a snapshot) from a repository in [Artifactory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_repository#Repository_managers). This artifact needs to be copied to a server (Linux) via a script.

What are my options? Something like [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) / [SCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy)? And how do I get the path of the artifact?

I found some solutions which require Artifactory Pro. But I just have Artifactory, not Artifactory Pro.

Is it possible at all to download from Artifactory without the UI and not having the Pro-Version? What is the experience?

I'm on OpenSUSE 12.1 (x86_64) if that matters.

Comment: See Artifactory documentation on this exact topic https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact

Comment: Once you have the path of the artifact, you can download it easily with WGet by adding the JFROG header with your user token.  https://coding-stream-of-consciousness.com/2019/06/23/download-secured-artifactory-artifact-with-wget-and-token/.  (though getting the latest artifact is another issue entirely of course).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Artifactory has a good extensive [REST-API](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API) and almost anything that can be done in the UI (perhaps even more) can also be done using simple HTTP requests.

The feature that you mention - retrieving the latest artifact, does indeed require the Pro edition; but it can also be achieved with a bit of work on your side and a few basic scripts.

**Option 1 - Search:**

Perform a [GAVC](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API#Artifactory%27sRESTAPI-GAVCSearch) search on a set of group ID and artifact ID coordinates to retrieve all existing versions of that set; then you can use any version string comparison algorithm to determine the latest version.

**Option 2 - the Maven way:**

Artifactory generates a standard [XML metadata](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-repository-metadata/) that is to be consumed by Maven, because Maven is faced with the same problem - determining the latest version; The metadata lists all available versions of an artifact and is generated for every artifact level folder; with a simple GET request and some XML parsing, you can discover the latest version.

Comment: the GAVC search is empty. Im deploying from Jenkins. Its a Free-Sytle-Job and a "Generic-Artifactory Integration" build. Does it need to be a Maven 2/3 Job or a Maven-Artifactory Integration build, to be able to Search by Maven coordinates? (When I dont deploy with Jenkins the search works)

Answer (score 80):

Something like the following bash script will retrieve the lastest `com.company:artifact` snapshot from the `snapshot` repo:

```
# Artifactory location
server=http://artifactory.company.com/artifactory
repo=snapshot

# Maven artifact location
name=artifact
artifact=com/company/$name
path=$server/$repo/$artifact
version=$(curl -s $path/maven-metadata.xml | grep latest | sed "s/.*<latest>\([^<]*\)<\/latest>.*/\1/")
build=$(curl -s $path/$version/maven-metadata.xml | grep '<value>' | head -1 | sed "s/.*<value>\([^<]*\)<\/value>.*/\1/")
jar=$name-$build.jar
url=$path/$version/$jar

# Download
echo $url
wget -q -N $url
```

It feels a bit dirty, yes, but it gets the job done.

Comment: I had to replace the "version=" line with version=`curl -s $path/maven-metadata.xml | grep "<version>" | sed "s/.*<version>\([^<]*\)<\/version>.*/\1/"`

Comment: This is not related with the question but it might help someone. 
Use *-k* with curl if you have problems with certificates.

Comment: for authentication I've use:
'version=`curl -u user:pwd -s $path/maven-metadata.xml | grep latest | sed "s/.*<latest>\([^<]*\)<\/latest>.*/\1/"`'

Comment: Using the "latest" value in maven-metadata is not a good idea.  It will appear to work right up until it doesn't, because it's not reliability updated after you switch to a new release version. See: http://articles.javatalks.ru/articles/32

Answer (score 20):

#### Using shell/unix tools

1. `curl 'http://$artiserver/artifactory/api/storage/$repokey/$path/$version/?lastModified'`

The above command responds with a JSON with two elements - "uri" and "lastModified"

2. Fetching the link in the uri returns another JSON which has the "downloadUri" of the artifact.
3. Fetch the link in the "downloadUri" and you have the latest artefact.

#### Using Jenkins Artifactory plugin

(Requires Pro) to resolve and download latest artifact, if Jenkins Artifactory plugin was used to publish to artifactory in another job:

1. Select Generic Artifactory Integration
2. Use Resolved Artifacts as
   `${repokey}:**/${component}*.jar;status=${STATUS}@${PUBLISH_BUILDJOB}#LATEST=>${targetDir}`

Comment: First solution also requires Pro, I am getting ""This REST API is available only in Artifactory Pro (see: http://www.jfrog.com/addons.php)"

Comment: I am using the pro version and it works with the build number but when I use the LATEST build number it cant find the artifact. Have you seen this problem before?

Comment: @Sateesh Potturu do you have a link to artifactory documentation for the syntax of the second suggestion?

Answer (score 8):

You could also use [Artifactory Query Language](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language) to get the latest artifact.

The following shell script is just an example. It uses 'items.find()' (which is available in the non-Pro version), e.g. `items.find({ "repo": {"$eq":"my-repo"}, "name": {"$match" : "my-file*"}})` that searches for files that have a repository name equal to "my-repo" and match all files that start with "my-file". Then it uses the [shell JSON parser ./jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to extract the latest file by sorting by the date field 'updated'. Finally it uses wget to download the artifact.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Artifactory settings
host="127.0.0.1"
username="downloader"
password="my-artifactory-token"

# Use Artifactory Query Language to get the latest scraper script (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language)
resultAsJson=$(curl -u$username:"$password" -X POST  http://$host/artifactory/api/search/aql -H "content-type: text/plain" -d 'items.find({ "repo": {"$eq":"my-repo"}, "name": {"$match" : "my-file*"}})')

# Use ./jq to pars JSON
latestFile=$(echo $resultAsJson | jq -r '.results | sort_by(.updated) [-1].name')

# Download the latest scraper script
wget -N -P ./libs/ --user $username --password $password http://$host/artifactory/my-repo/$latestFile
```

Comment: Just consider that AQL was introduced in Artifactory V3.5.0

Comment: you may need to add the `path` that results in `resultAsJson` while trying to download the artifact

Comment: thanks very good answer, it can be one more step reduced. Instead of **jq**, you can `.sort({"$desc" : ["created"]}).limit(1)` at the end of this part `{"$match" : "my-file*"}})`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the REST-API's "[Item last modified](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ItemLastModified)". From the docs, it retuns something like this:

```
GET /api/storage/libs-release-local/org/acme?lastModified
{
"uri": "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/storage/libs-release-local/org/acme/foo/1.0-SNAPSHOT/foo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom",
"lastModified": ISO8601
}
```

Example:

```
# Figure out the URL of the last item modified in a given folder/repo combination
url=$(curl \
    -H 'X-JFrog-Art-Api: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
    'http://<artifactory-base-url>/api/storage/<repo>/<folder>?lastModified'  | jq -r '.uri')
# Figure out the name of the downloaded file
downloaded_filename=$(echo "${url}" | sed -e 's|[^/]*/||g')
# Download the file
curl -L -O "${url}"
```

Comment: Just consider that the use of "X-JFrog-Art-Api" for authentication is supported since version 4.4.3. It will not work with older versions.

Comment: problem is, lastModified does not necessarily mean latest build

Comment: Did you find any ways to find the latest version available and update the cache? Appreciate if you can help. Thanks @FlorianCastellane

Answer (score 5):

With recent versions of artifactory, you can query this through the api.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact

If you have a maven artifact with 2 snapshots

name => 'com.acme.derp'
version => 0.1.0
repo name => 'foo'
snapshot 1 => derp-0.1.0-20161121.183847-3.jar
snapshot 2 => derp-0.1.0-20161122.00000-0.jar

Then the full paths would be

> https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/foo/com/acme/derp/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/derp-0.1.0-20161121.183847-3.jar

and

> https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/foo/com/acme/derp/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/derp-0.1.0-20161122.00000-0.jar

You would fetch the latest like so:

```
curl https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/foo/com/acme/derp/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/derp-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

The role of Artifactory is to provide files for [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) (as well as other build tools such as Ivy, Gradle or sbt). You can just use Maven together with the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) to copy the artifacts out. Here's a [pom](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html) outline to start you off...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>A group id</groupId>
    <artifactId>An artifact id</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>The group id of your artifact</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>The artifact id</artifactId>
                                    <version>The snapshot version</version>
                                    <type>Whatever the type is, for example, JAR</type>
                                    <outputDirectory>Where you want the file to go</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Just run `mvn install` to do the copy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `wget --user=USER --password=PASSWORD ..` command, but before you can do that, you must allow artifactory to force authentication, which can be done by **unchecking** the "***Hide Existence of Unauthorized Resources***" box at **Security/General** tab in **artifactory admin panel**. Otherwise artifactory sends a 404 page and wget can not authenticate to artifactory.

Answer (score 2):

This may be new:

https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/repo/com/example/foo/1.0.[RELEASE]/foo-1.0.[RELEASE].tgz

For loading module foo from example.com .  Keep the [RELEASE] parts verbatim.  This is mentioned in the docs but it's not made abundantly clear that you can actually put [RELEASE] into the URL (as opposed to a substitution pattern for the developer).

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in my version of Artifactory (5.3.2).

Comment: According to [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact) this requires Artifactory Pro.

Comment: You can also use `SNAPSHOT` verbatim according to the documentation Daniel links to.  But it is only for Pro :( .... so go back and grab one of the two-step script answers that you skipped over hoping there was a way to do it in one step.

Comment: Artifactory seems to have an undocumented habit of changing its behavior depending on your user agent. This means that while the suggested pattern does work with Artifactory Pro, it only does when you are using wget, curl or similar tools.
For browsers you get a 404 because Artifactory attempts to redirect you to a path that has "[RELEASE]" in it verbatim (not resolved to whatever is appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

For me the easiest way was to read the last versions of the project with a combination of curl, grep, sort and tail.

My format: service-(version: 1.9.23)-(buildnumber)156.tar.gz

```
versionToDownload=$(curl -u$user:$password 'https://$artifactory/artifactory/$project/' | grep -o 'service-[^"]*.tar.gz' | sort | tail -1)
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download the latest jar between 2 repositores, you can use this solution. I actually use it within my Jenkins pipeline, it works perfectly. Let's say you have a plugins-release-local and plugins-snapshot-local and you want to download the latest jar between these. Your shell script should look like this

**NOTE : I use [jfrog cli](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI) and it's configured with my Artifactory server.**

## Use case : Shell script

```
# your repo, you can change it then or pass an argument to the script
# repo = $1 this get the first arg passed to the script
repo=plugins-snapshot-local
# change this by your artifact path, or pass an argument $2
artifact=kshuttle/ifrs16
path=$repo/$artifact
echo $path
~/jfrog rt download --flat $path/maven-metadata.xml version/
version=$(cat version/maven-metadata.xml | grep latest | sed "s/.*<latest>\([^<]*\)<\/latest>.*/\1/")
echo "VERSION $version"
~/jfrog rt download --flat $path/$version/maven-metadata.xml build/
build=$(cat  build/maven-metadata.xml | grep '<value>' | head -1 | sed "s/.*<value>\([^<]*\)<\/value>.*/\1/")
echo "BUILD $build"
# change this by your app name, or pass an argument $3
name=ifrs16
jar=$name-$build.jar
url=$path/$version/$jar

# Download
echo $url
~/jfrog rt download --flat $url
```

## Use case : Jenkins Pipeline

```
def getLatestArtifact(repo, pkg, appName, configDir){
    sh """
        ~/jfrog rt download --flat $repo/$pkg/maven-metadata.xml $configDir/version/
        version=\$(cat $configDir/version/maven-metadata.xml | grep latest | sed "s/.*<latest>\\([^<]*\\)<\\/latest>.*/\\1/")
        echo "VERSION \$version"
        ~/jfrog rt download --flat $repo/$pkg/\$version/maven-metadata.xml $configDir/build/
        build=\$(cat  $configDir/build/maven-metadata.xml | grep '<value>' | head -1 | sed "s/.*<value>\\([^<]*\\)<\\/value>.*/\\1/")
        echo "BUILD \$build"
        jar=$appName-\$build.jar
        url=$repo/$pkg/\$version/\$jar

        # Download
        echo \$url
        ~/jfrog rt download --flat \$url
    """
}

def clearDir(dir){
    sh """
        rm -rf $dir/*
    """

}

node('mynode'){
    stage('mysstage'){
        def repos =  ["plugins-snapshot-local","plugins-release-local"]

        for (String repo in repos) {
            getLatestArtifact(repo,"kshuttle/ifrs16","ifrs16","myConfigDir/")
        }
        //optional
        clearDir("myConfigDir/")
    }
}
```

This helps alot when you want to get the latest package between 1 or more repos. Hope it helps u too!
For more Jenkins scripted pipelines info, visit [Jenkins docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline).

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
     curl  -sS http://the_repo/com/stackoverflow/the_artifact/maven-metadata.xml | grep latest | awk -F'<latest>' '{print $2}' | awk -F'</latest>' '{print $1}'
```

With sed:

```
    curl  -sS http://the_repo/com/stackoverflow/the_artifact/maven-metadata.xml | grep latest | sed 's:<latest>::' | sed 's:</latest>::'
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to download an artifact in a Dockerfile, instead of using wget or curl or the likes you can simply use the 'ADD' directive:

ADD ${ARTIFACT_URL} /opt/app/app.jar

Of course, the tricky part is determining the ARTIFACT_URL, but there's enough about that in all the other answers.

However, [Docker best practises](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) strongly discourage using ADD for this purpose and recommend using wget or curl.

Answer (score 0):

No one mention **xmllint** aka proper xml parser, install it with:

```
sudo apt-get update -qq
sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-utils
```

use it:

```
ART_URL="https://artifactory.internal.babycorp.com/artifactory/api-snapshot/com/babycorp/baby-app/CD-684-my-branch-SNAPSHOT"
ART_VERSION=`curl -s $ART_URL/maven-metadata.xml | xmllint --xpath '//snapshotVersion[1]/value/text()' -`
```

and finally:

```
curl -s -o baby-app.jar ${ART_URL}/baby-app-${ART_VERSION}.jar
```

or

```
wget ${ART_URL}/baby-app-${ART_VERSION}.jar
```

to keep the filename

Answer (score 0):

If using [the JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory), this can be done in a single line as follows:

`jf rt dl "path/to/artifacts/-/" --sort-by=created --sort-order=desc --limit=1`

(The above is for v2 but think the v1 command should be the same but substituting `jf` with `jfrog`.)