# Is there a URL for the latest snapshot for an artifact in Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

I would like to make a permalink to the latest snapshot version of an artifact in Artifactory. If we are on 1.0-SNAPSHOT, I would like a URL that downloads the latest 1.0-SNAPSHOT JAR. I can find the latest artifact by locating the artifact on our server at `http://hostname/artifactory/libs-snapshot/groupId/artifactId/1.0-SNAPSHOT/`. Other than checking the timestamps, I can figure out which one if the latest by opening maven-metadata.xml and matching metadata/versioning/snapshot timestamp and buildNumber with a JAR in the same directory. This could be scripted, but ideally Artifactory already has a way to construct a permalink in this manner. Does Artifactory provide such a URL?

Comment: Ever get a solution Ben?

Comment: @RoyTruelove No, I never got a working solution. I've switched projects so it's no longer my problem.

Answer (score 6):

Doing the normal query for the entry with artifactId-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in the URL name should return automatically the latest snapshot.
See the doc [here](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact)

One thing: This is base either on the latest creation date if no pom present, or latest creation of the pom if there are some. Mixing pom and non-pom deployment may results in strange results!

Comment: Thank you for linking to the documentation. I've tried your solution but my Artifactory instance returns a 404.

Comment: From the page: Notes: Requires Artifactory Pro. Argh.

Answer (score 2):

I tried using shell script and it worked for me.

**Step1**: Get an encrypted password for your user account by clicking on user name or create a common user. Go to using your secure password section in the following link
http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Centrally+Secure+Passwords

**Step 2**: In your local machine create a temp folder and type this curl(may be wget for windows) command:

```
curl -o tmp/foo.jar --user <username>:<encrypted_password> <artifactory_url>/list/libs-snapshot-local/com/search/foo/1.0/foo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.JAR
```

Your foo.jar in tmp folder is latest version. If we dont give timestamp as like above, it will download latest artifact in that version. Hope this helps!

Comment: This only works with Artifactory Pro, but if you've got it the key for me was  */list/* in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful:

[How to download the latest artifact from Artifactory repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989033/how-do-i-download-the-latest-artifact-from-artifactory)

Although there is no permalink ability in the free version of Artifactory, it can be scripted easily as you suggest. I have provided a quick script to do that in the referenced question.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another portable option is to use the maven command line:

`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get -DartifactId=[artifactId] -DgroupId=[groupId] -Dversion=[version] -Ddest=[dest file]`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (no search API, just direct artifact URL):

```
curl -O -J --user <username>:<encrypted_password> http://hostname/artifactory/libs-snapshot/groupId/artifactId/1.0-SNAPSHOT/artifactId-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Basically using 1.0-SNAPSHOT in the artifact name downloads the latest version of 1.0-SNAPSHOT snapshot.