# Trying to download JAR from Artifactory. Maven searches local repository instead of public maven server

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

My goal is to make a Jenkins job that downloads lastest jar from Artifactory.
I'm trying to use Maven default command `clean` and `install` but job fails.
Maven should be downloading them from `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/` but Jenkins tries to download them from my local Artifactory repository `http://localhost:8081/artifactory/bpidev/`.

**Jenkins Fail Log** :

```
Jenkins Artifactory Plugin version: 2.7.2
Artifactory integration is enabled
[S3_CbbCustom_Deploy_UAT] $ java -classpath /jenkins/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar -Dmaven.home=/jenkins/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven -DbuildInfoConfig.propertiesFile=/tmp/buildInfo6009671373604071834.properties -Dm3plugin.lib=/jenkins/jenkins/cache/artifactory-plugin/2.7.2 -Dclassworlds.conf=/tmp/classworlds1010245859327507063conf -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/S3_CbbCustom_Deploy_UAT/pom.xml org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -f pom.xml install
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Scanning for projects...
[main] INFO org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorderLifecycleParticipant - [buildinfo] Properties file found at '/tmp/buildInfo6009671373604071834.properties'
[main] INFO org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder - Initializing Artifactory Build-Info Recording
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------< cbp.cbb:cbb-custom-3 >------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Building cbb-custom-3 [4.3.3,)
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/bpidev/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom
[main] WARNING org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer - The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from artifactory-release: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/bpidev/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.jar
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - BUILD FAILURE
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Total time:  0.563 s
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Finished at: 2022-05-02T15:02:03+08:00
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 in artifactory-release (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/bpidev/) -> [Help 1]
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - 
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - 
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
Build step 'Invoke Artifactory Maven 3' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Artifactory Maven 3' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

---

**Target jar**
[image: This is the target jar]

**Jenkins configuration**
[image: Jenkins settings]

**pom.xml I used**
[image]

---

Question 1. My goal is to make a Jenkins job that downloads lastest jar from Artifactory.
Am I doing it right? or is there a much simpler way?

Question 2. Why is Maven searching local Artifactory for its plugins? Where is the connnect?

Question 3. Can I make Maven to download its plugins from  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/? or should I just upload `clean` and `install` to my Artifactory repository?

Comment: solved the problem by fixing the pom.xml.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989033/how-to-download-the-latest-artifact-from-artifactory-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your configuration for 'Resolution release repository' contains a local Artifactory repository.
Instead, you should point it to a virtual repository.

[Virtual repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Virtual+Repositories) will aggregate your local repository 'bpidev' and another remote repository which will point to  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.

Maven depends on the settings.xml generated, so if it is configured to point to 'bpidev' only, he wont be able to reach the remote repository.

plugins resolution is also configured through the settings.xml as 'pluginRepository' which can also point to the same virtual repository in Artifactory which can aggregates the same remote repository so Maven will be able to download the plugins.

Comment: The main problem is solved, but I still can't download the jar file. It says `JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!`. I'm not compiling anthing. I just want to download the jar from the artifactory.

Comment: nevermind. fixed the pom file to download the jar.